# How do I extract information inside nested div from website with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to scrape information from a table inside a `div` element.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://www.concorindia.com/containerquery.aspx"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set Doc = IE.document
    
    IE.document.getElementById("contno").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").Range("B3").Value
    Doc.getElementById("CONTButton1").Click       
    
    Set Data = Doc.getElementById("PPosition")
      
End Sub
```

I intended to extract the information inside div element by getting all the data inside the div id "PPosition" first but the message box shows

> error 13: Type Mismatch

How can I get information inside the table mentioned in the code like train number, originating status, etc.?

Sample container number - TCNU4171692

The website from which the data is to be **scraped** is also mentioned in the code. (http://www.concorindia.com/containerquery.aspx)

Comment: Would it be possible to share a valid container number?

Comment: Yes sure. TCNU4171692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general way to printout the entire HTML table into a worksheet:

```
Sub ScrapeContainerInfo()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim div As HTMLDivElement
Dim table As HTMLTable
Dim tableRow As HTMLTableRow
Dim tableCell As HTMLTableCell
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim url As String, containerNumber As String, reqBody As String


Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
containerNumber = "TCNU4171692"
url = "http://www.concorindia.com/containerquery.aspx"
reqBody = "__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE1Njk0Mzk4MzkPZBYCAgoPZBYEAgEPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkAgMPZBYEAgMPEGRkFgFmZAIFDw9kFgIeB29uY2xpY2sFIWphdmFzY3JpcHQ6ZXJyPXRlc3QoKTtyZXR1cm4gZXJyO2RkS1KgJsS2Kb22YOy%2FEN0XTBRc8lY%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBgKk%2BrO6AwKhk42ICgKmqIGHDAKbyfWzBQLvyamyBQKxlra5AfFIxQQ%2BvdUNsDciaOk4g0LyycSG&contno=" & containerNumber & "&drpimpexp=Any&CONTButton1=Submit+Query"

With req
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send reqBody
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set div = doc.getElementById("PPosition")
Set table = div.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

i = 1
For Each tableRow In table.Rows
    i = i + 1
    j = 1
    For Each tableCell In tableRow.Cells
        j = j + 1
        sht.Cells(i, j) = tableCell.innerText
    Next tableCell

Next tableRow

End Sub
```

References used: `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Micrsoft WinHTTP Services Version 5.1`

The output looks like that:

[image]

Now, if you want to access the table's info in a more targeted way you ca do it like so:

```
Debug.Print table.Rows(1).Cells(0).innerText
```

The code above prints the first cell of the second row of the table, in the immediate window. You can modify it accordingly to access any cell, keeping in mind that the index starts from `0`.

**EDIT**

I mistakenly thought that getting the actual HTML response was not an issue, but since it apparently is, I have updated the code to include the HTTP request that needs to be sent. I avoid using IE whenever it's possible.

I have hardcoded one specific container number. This can easily be modified to loop through multiple container numbers.

Comment: Does it work for you? Is the data scrapped on a worksheet?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't post it otherwise ;)

Comment: Shows error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set on  Set table = div.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner and I don't know how to figure this out ;) Will try once again

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want. Could you please tell me how you stored the HTML locally?

Comment: @RonitAgarwal I thought that getting the HTML was not an issue for you, since as you said you have successfully extracted info. Anyway, I updated the code. It uses a different, more efficient approach, than using IE.

Comment: @RonitAgarwal  Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: You've hard coded the event validation and view state as well which will almost certainly change at some point - just so OP is aware.

Comment: @StavrosJon Sure. Thanks again.

Comment: @QHarr Hi. Is there anything I can do to make this better?

Comment: Dimension an array according to the table dimensions and populate that. Then write that out once to the worksheet to reduce i/o with sheet. See if ev and vs can accurately be captured from prior request.  Early bound is quicker but does require, in this instance, for all users to have the ability to check the HTML Object Library in references. The answer above is very good though. +

Comment: Absolutely. This works perfectly. I just didn't understand the hard coding of view state, hence asked. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @StavrosJon. Can we possible bypass captcha when we try to scrape data?

Comment: @RonitAgarwal That's a good one..I suggest you post a new question about it providing more details ;)

Comment: @StavrosJon I read about it. People have shared major concerns ;) Also the viewstate and eventvalidation changes frequently. Do I just copy the whole viewstate and eventvalidation from the HTML code in the VBA code?

Comment: @StavrosJon I know it's annoying but this is the last help I seek to run this code. The original lot of 40 containers which also contains the container number I gave as a sample to you runs perfectly. All the 40 containers are updated on one click. The problem arises when I take a different lot which is obviously due to change in event validation and viewstate. I read and tried reading about extracting it but I am a beginner and hence could not execute it. If only you can guide me?

Comment: @RonitAgarwal go to your browser's developer tools and inspect the network traffic (CTRL+ Shift + E if you're using firefox) when you hit the `Submit Query` button. The first request that pops up is a POST request. It's the same request as the one we are sending via VBA in the code above. If you inspect this request you will see its parameters among which are the event validation and viewstate. You can copy the strings from there and update the code.